# How to enable only Standard Edition features in SQL Server 2005 Dev Edition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got the following problem.

We have Development, Testing and Production environments for our system. All these environments will contain SQL Server 2005, but different editions. The Production will work with Standard Edition.

Now we would like to install Dev Edition on other servers (to save our money), but as far as I know, Dev Edition has the same features as Enterprise and it can theoretically cause some problems after publishing the system on production.

How can one disable all Enterprise specific features in Dev Edition? Or is it another way to make Dev Edition to work as Standard one?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there' no way to "dumb down" the developer edition to handle only the feature that are present in SQL Server Standard Edition.

You'll just have to make sure you and your team aren't using any Enterprise-/Developer-only features.

Comment: +1 - See also: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sqlman/archive/2010/08/22/making-developer-edition-of-sql-server-act-look-like-standard-edition.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But it is unclear for me: are these features disabled by default? If no, how they can be easily disabled?

Comment: @Eugene: no, the Developer edition is identical to the Enterprise edition, so the Enterprise features are present in the Dev edition, and they **cannot** be disabled

Comment: I ment something else. For example, the feature Online Indexing is off by default. So, if one will turn it on, then it is Enterprise. I understand though, that 4 CPUs cannot be emulated as 1, so the performance issue will appear (hm, virtualization can help). I'll investigate this problem in details and write here my results, when something interesting appears.